# App is incompatible with LGE Nexus 4 and 5

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-min-sdk, target-sdk

I recently updated my app (I don't remember what I did) and now it doesn't show up in the PlayStore nor download to my Nexus 4, Nexus 5, nor Nexus 9. What about my target SDK or build gradle is causing this to happen? My account has no alerts and the app hasn't been removed for any reason. Erg.

**Top-level build file:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**My main module build file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:21'
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            //runProguard false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.5.0@aar'
    compile 'com.github.antonyt:InfiniteViewPager:v1.0.0'
    compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    // recyclerview
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    // google analytics
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
    // pager sliding strip
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    // http library (for using beanstream REST)
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
    // amaazon S3 uploads
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.1.+'
    // paypal purchasing
    compile files('libs/PayPalAndroidSDK-2.7.1.jar')
    // Module dependency on ParseLoginUI library sources
    compile project(':ParseLoginUI')
    // Parse libs
    compile files('libs/ParseCrashReporting-1.9.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.1.jar')
    // android support v4
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    // facebook SDK
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    //butterknife
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    // Subsampling-scale-image-view (for templating)
    //compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.1.4'
    compile files('libs/AppRater.jar')
}
```

**My ParseLoginUI module's build file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'

    provided 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
    // This assumes that your app's project has a compile dependency on the Parse SDK JAR files.
    // Your project's build.gradle should say:
    //
    //     compile files('YOUR_PROJECT_LIBS_PATH/Parse-1.9.1.jar')
    //     compile files('YOUR_PROJECT_LIBS_PATH/ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.1.jar')
    //
    // Since the dependency below is "provided" instead of "compile", your project's build.gradle
    // does not have to refer to the same Parse SDK instance that's in the ParseLoginUI/libs folder.
    provided files("$rootProject.projectDir/ParseLoginUI/libs/Parse-1.9.1.jar")
    provided files("$rootProject.projectDir/ParseLoginUI/libs/ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.1.jar")
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.test"
    android:versionCode="41"
    android:versionName="3.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

  <!--  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    -->

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>

    <!--<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />-->

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.setParameters" />

    <!--
      IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
      to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
    -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
                     android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
                     android:protectionLevel="normal"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"/>

    <!--
      IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.tutorials.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
      to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
    -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.app.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.app.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.app.test.GlobalApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity.PARSE_LOGIN_ENABLED"
            android:value="true" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity.PARSE_LOGIN_ENABLED"
                android:value="true" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity.FACEBOOK_LOGIN_ENABLED"
                android:value="true" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity.TWITTER_LOGIN_ENABLED"
                android:value="true" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/parse_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
            android:value="@string/parse_client_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.app.test.notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <activity
            android:name=".DispatchActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".IntroActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UserSettingsActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/PreferenceScreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EditProfileActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName=".EditProfileActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChangePasswordActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName=".ChangePasswordActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PaymentDetailsActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName=".PaymentDetailsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PurchaseActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.app.test.GalleryActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.app.test.FeedActivityV2"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.app.test.SearchActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName="com.app.test.FeedActivityV2"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.app.test.SuggestedUserActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName="com.app.test.FeedActivityV2"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.app.test.CommentsActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName="com.app.test.FeedActivityV2"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.app.test.NotificationsActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName="com.app.test.FeedActivityV2"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentMethodActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalFuturePaymentActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.FuturePaymentConsentActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.FuturePaymentInfoActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalProfileSharingActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.ProfileSharingConsentActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="io.card.payment.CardIOActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name="io.card.payment.DataEntryActivity" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.app.test.ContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.app"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name=".PaymentProcessingActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_payment_processing" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.app.test.WrapperWeb"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_wrapper_web" >
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <!-- Custom Receiver -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".Receiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- End Custom Receiver -->

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <!-- IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.tutorials.pushnotifications" to match your app's package name. -->
                <category android:name="com.app.test" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- replace @drawable/push_icon with your push icon identifier -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.app.test.FeedActivitySingle"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_feed_activity_single"
            android:parentActivityName="com.app.test.GalleryActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.app.test.GalleryActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you can compare your latest code by history in android studio. maybe you can find the problem your self.

Comment: You must have done something.  Because it shows as incompatible with ALL my devices.  And I've never seen that before.

Comment: Yeah that's kind of shitty! Haha. I didn't get a message from Google or anything. No holds on my account. Is it at least possible that something in the code itself, and not the build files, could be causing this? Could the iml files be causing this?

Comment: Did you edit  the list devices while uploading to playstore? This will overwrite your manifest settings.

Comment: @Ahmed I had no idea this was possible. I better check. Where can I find those settings?

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1286017

Comment: @Ahmed It says 0 supported devices and 0 excluded devices.

Comment: Strange. Can you post your manifest here?

Comment: @Ahmed I edited my post to include the Manifest. I'm pretty sure it's some kind of misspelling or incorrect inclusion of one of the permissions. I'm just not sure which.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96934/discussion-between-bluemunch-and-ahmed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had set features for different camera functions when I only had to set the permissions.

**Solution here:** [My app all of a sudden has 0 supported devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34078075/my-app-all-of-a-sudden-has-0-supported-devices/34078162#34078162)

Comment: So your suggestion is not to include features unless absolutely necessary?

Comment: I suppose so. That was the only thing that worked for me.